# How do I test if numbers are in a list in an if statement?

Tags: python

```
if ('0' or '13' or '26' or '39') in user and accumulator + 11 <= 21:
    accumulator += 11
    print 'ADDING 11!!!!!'
elif ('0' or '13' or '26' or '39') in user:
    accumulator + 1
    print 'ADDING 1'
```

This is out of context of the entire program. I have the `print` statements in there for debugging purposes, however, I am having trouble with the `if` statement determining whether or not the 0, 13, 26, or 39 is in the list `user`, and the `accumulator + 11` wont go over 21. I have tried it without the parenthesis and the single quotes, any advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you're checking for integers rather that strings containing ASCII digits, yes, leave off the single quotes.

You mean

```
if any(x in user for x in ('0', '13', '26', '39')) and accumulator + 11 <= 21:
```

Which does what it says -- it checks if any of those strings (or numbers, if you remove the quotes) are in the list `user`.

You need to make the same change to the `elif`.

Also, you mean

```
accumulator += 1
```

instead of

```
accumulator + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
accumulator + 1
```

should be

```
accumulator += 1
```

Comment: That line is never even reached because his `if` statements are wrong. He knows that because of the `print` statements he includes.

Answer (score 0):

As @agf has mentioned, using `any` for multiple `or` and using `all` for multiple `and` would be the natural way to deal with the mentioned problem, there can be another approach using set

for example

*given*

```
user1=['1','13','25']
and
user2=['0','1','13','14','26','27','39']
```

`if ('0' or '13' or '26' or '39') in user1`

*which is generally written as*

```
any(x in user1 for x in ['0' , '13' , '26' , '39'])
```

*can also be written as*

```
not set(['0' , '13' , '26' , '39']).isdisjoint(user1)
or
len(set(['0' , '13' , '26' , '39']).intersection(user1))>0
```

**and similarly**

```
if ('0' and '13' and '26' and '39') in user2
```

*which is generally written as*

```
all(x in user2 for x in ['0' , '13' , '26' , '39'])
```

*can also be written as*

```
len(set(['0' , '13' , '26' , '39']).difference(user2)) == 0
```

so back to your problem, using set intersection we can write as

```
if not set(['0' , '13' , '26' , '39']).isdisjoint(user1) and accumulator + 11 <= 21:
    accumulator += 11
    print 'ADDING 11!!!!!'
elif ('0' or '13' or '26' or '39') in user:
    accumulator += 1
    print 'ADDING 1'
```

Comment: In general, instead of testing the `len` against zero, just use the fact that an empty `set` evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers are good, but they might not be clear to someone new to Python. Here is something that is clearer (but not as pythonic, possibly slower on cases where the no lookup number is in *user*, and etc...yes, I know).

```
lookup_numbers = ['0', '13', '26', '39']
num_found = False
for lookup_number in lookup_numbers:
  if lookup_number in user:
    num_found = True
    break

if num_found:
  if ((accumulator + 11) <= 21):
    accumulator += 11
  else:
    accumulator += 1
```

Note: if your *user* list contains strings, then keep the quotes for each entry in *lookup_numbers*. It if contains integers, remove the quotes.

Comment: The logic is not equivalent. The `else` clause here is reached even if none of the numbers match, where he appears to only want to reach it if they do match but the accumulator test does not. Also, your accumulator test happens multiple times, which is unnecessary.